# Shrink UIView from left to right

Tags: ios, uiview, shrink

I have the following code to shrink a UIView from left to right and remove it from super view after the animation finished:

```
    UIView* coverView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50)];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"swipe_rl.png"]];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [imageView setFrame:coverView.bounds];
    [coverView addSubview:imageView];
    [coverView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    coverView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:coverView];
    CGRect frame = coverView.frame ;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
    [coverView setFrame:CGRectMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, frame.origin.y, 0, frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [coverView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

However, the left part of the picture stays and the right part of the picture disappears as you can see in the pictures. For a specific purpose, I want the left part disappears and the right part stays. How can I do it?

For those who want to know why I want this:

```
- Basically, I want a display-from-left-to-right animation (It means you have a picture and the left of the picture appears first and the the middle and the whole picture appears)
- I do this by adding a second view above the first picture and then shrink the second view from left to right. The first view will then be revealed from left to right.
- Look at http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b510/yenmach/right_to_left_zps80b9e9bb.jpg and http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b510/yenmach/left_to_right_zps9214dc4a.jpg
```

[image: shrink from the beginning]

[image: shrink in the middle of animation]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Are you trying to reveal an image, or make one disappear? When I tried your code, the image appeared whole, then disappeared from left to right.

Comment: I'm trying to shrink one image (image A) from left to right to reveal image B which is below image A .

Comment: Please look at http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b510/yenmach/right_to_left_zps3c636e69.jpg
And http://i1289.photobucket.com/albums/b510/yenmach/left_to_right_zpsd5ae1f64.jpg, you'll see the problem

Comment: Which image is the one you show above? Is that the one you're revealing (B), or the one you're shrinking (A)?

Comment: In the two urls above, the white photo is the lower. the upper photo is fit with the screen and hide the white photo at first. Then the upper photo shrinks and reveals the lower photo. 

In the questions I posted, I used the white photo to demonstrate that the left part of a photo, when shrinking, always stays, and the right part of a photo disappears. It may cause you some misunderstanding. I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

//try this.......

```
 CGRect frame = coverView.frame ;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - 2*frame.size.width,imageView.frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
coverView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x + frame.size.width, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: the code above moves the view from right to left, not from left to right

Comment: it's not working. the picture is moving the the left and the view is shrinking from left to right, but I want the picture to stay there.

Comment: @user1468878 You have to comment the UIView animation method in your code and add this code instead of that. Have you did like that?

Comment: In fact, the following code works: 
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x - 2*frame.size.width,imageView.frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
coverView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x + 1.667*frame.size.width, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

Changing the position of imageView and coverView in opposite direction somehow "stop" the image from moving from right to left. But this is kind of hack:

Comment: If you ask me where I get the number 1.667, I say: I try different number. If I use 1, the image move to the left. If I use 2, the image move to the right. Then I use try-and-fail method to get the exact number to "stop" the image: 1.667. In my real project, however, right number is 1.5425. I don't know if my app is rejected for this kind of hack

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution but a workaround, If you are going to be using this with a consistent background (ideally a solid colour) you could just have another view animate overtop of the image view and then remove both once the animation is done.

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you wanted to do this with photos. Guess my solution wouldn't be the best in that case. Unless if you added the photo on top and used that to "uncover" it.

Comment: yes I'm not doing the "uncover-from-left-to-right" animation with a consistent background. That's why I need "the left part of photo disappears and the right part stays"

Answer (score 0):

Try changing UIImageView [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW99) property,

```
[imageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeRight];
```

I was having same kind of requirement and this worked fine for me at that time.

Comment: It does not works. I think the above code only aligns the image in the imageView. Even when I run 
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x+ frame.size.width,imageView.frame.origin.y, 0, frame.size.height);
The image will then be resized when the imageView shrink from left to right